# How to compare two files and print matching in 3rd file using Perl

Tags: perl

**file1.csv**

abc,hello

bac,man

cac,tan

**file2.csv**

cav,

pan, 

bac,

and,
**Outfile:** The out file should have following as this match to file2.csv

bac

Comment: First try yourself and show us your code. Then we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!C:\Perl\perl\bin\perl.exe                                  

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = "file1.csv";
my $file2 = "file2.csv";

my @a_file1 = &sub_read ($file1);
my @a_file2 = &sub_read ($file2);

foreach my $entry1 (@a_file1) {
    foreach my $entry2 (@a_file2) {
        if ($entry1 eq $entry2) {
            print "$entry1\n";
        }
    }   
}

sub sub_read {
    my $file = $_[0];
    my @a_file;
    open (READ,"<",$file) or die "$!";
    while (<READ>) {
        chomp ($_);
        my @a_temp = split(/\,/,$_);
        foreach my $a (@a_temp) {
            push (@a_file, $a);
        }
    }
    close (READ);
    return @a_file;
}
```

I think this shoudl work.
To print the File simply use something like this:

```
open (WRITE, ">> $outfile");
print WRITE "$entry1\n";
close (WRITE);
```

There are plenty of possibilities to this (using a hash).

Comment: Using a hash would reduce the cost to O(N+M) from O(N*M)

Answer (score -1):

```
open( FILE2, "file2.csv" );
open( FILE1, "file1.csv" );

while (<FILE1>) {
    my $element1 = $_;
    push( @file1, $element1 );
}

while (<FILE2>) {

    my $element2 = $_;

    if ( grep( /^$element2$/, @file1 ) ) {
        print "$element1 exists in file1.csv \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Initially store the first file contents line based in a array and then to compare each line of second file with each element of the array.comaprision is by grep to check whether $element exists in the array @file1.hope this helps.

Comment: alternatives to using grep are  

1) if ("$element1" ~ @file1)
2)if ( any(@file1) eq "$element1" )

Comment: This answer would be much improved if it were edited to include the description. As it stands, comments are transient.